# Serialization of all objects involved on a signature whit iText

Tags: java, serialization, itext, digital-signature

I've been using iText for sign pdf documents since version 2.
Days ago, I found a white paper by Bruno Lowagie  about "Digital Signature for PDF Documents".

He write about signing a document on the server using a signature created on the client, a feature that I have implemeted two years ago.

Like Bruno propose on his paper to do this, I write the objects involved on the server disk.
The problem I found at first time was I need to serialize all I wanted to write.

Nowdays I consider moving to a newest version of iText and my questions are:

Anyone knows if the last realease of iText the objects involved on a sign implements Serializable?
Anyone has the same problem and know a solution less costly instead of serialized all of these objects?

Comment: I doubt serialization will help you along.

Comment: The above being said,  itext now knows the concept of deferred signatures more explicitly than in earlier days. You should look that way.

Comment: I think this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831200/replace-signature-content-in-a-pdf solves my question